# UV face vectors not showing up on uv/image editor textures

Tags: uv, texture-coordinates

[image]

as you can see a grew ghost frame shows up in paint mode

[image]

but nothing shows up in mask mode

[image]

if i hit X on the texture then this shows up. how do i see this with its texture underneath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the answer online apparently in cycles uv local view needs to be turned off

[image]